# Efficiently storing objects allowing rapid access to highest value (hashmap vs. priority queue)

Tags: algorithm

So I have a set of objects X, and each of them has a value v[x].

How can I store the objects X in a way that allows me to efficiently compute the x with the highest value?

Also I would like to be able to change the value of v[x], and have x automatically fall to the correct place in the data structure.

I thought about using a priority queue for this but my friend told me I should use a hashmap instead.  Which confused me because hashmaps are unordered.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, and your friend is wrong: hash map is not going to work, because it is unordered. Hash map may be useful if you wish to maintain values `v` externally to your objects `x`, but then it would need a separate data structure, in addition to the one providing the ordering.

Priority queue with a comparator that compares the value `v` attached to the object `x` will provide you with a fast way to get the object with the highest value.

No matter what data structure you are going to use, it would be up to you to update it when the value `v[x]` changes. Generally, you will need to remove the object from the structure, and then insert it back right away, so that it could be placed at its new position according to its updated value.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 operations that you wish to support efficiently:

1. Find maximum
2. Update value

For #1, a priority queue (i.e. [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29)) is a good idea, but it doesn't allow you to efficiently do #2 - you'll have to look through the whole queue to find the correct node, then update and move (or delete and reinsert) it - this takes `O(n)`.

To support #2 efficiently, you can use a hash map *in addition* to a priority queue (perhaps this is what your friend was talking about) - have each object map to the applicable node in the tree, then you can find the correct node in expected `O(1)` and update it in `O(log n)`.

As an alternative, you can use a [(self-balancing) binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree). You'll firstly sort on the value, then on a unique member of the object (like a unique ID). This will allow you to find any object in `O(log n)`. #1 can be implemented to take `O(1)` and #2 will take `O(log n)` (through delete and reinsert).

Lastly, for completeness, elements in a hash map are unordered - you'll have to look through all the values to find the maximum (i.e. it takes `O(n)`) (but update can be performed in expected `O(1)`).

Summary:

```
            Find Max   Update
Heap only   O(1)       O(n)
Heap + HM   O(1)       O(log n) (expected)
BST         O(1)       O(log n)
HM only     O(n)       O(1) (expected)
```